# How to get relative path of uploaded file as variable in php (repost)

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

How can I get the relative path to my uploaded file? For example if I upload test.png I would get /upload/test.png. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Jquery Ajax File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Profile image</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-image"></i></span> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profile_image" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="" >
                 <label class="btn btn-default btn-file input-group-addon">
    Browse <input type="file" name="image" style="display: none;" onchange="myFunction()" id="image" >
</label>
<div class="result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $('#image').change(function(e){
            var file = this.files[0];
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append('image', file);
            $.ajax({
                url : "http://192.168.1.147/upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data : form,
                success: function(response){
                    $('.result').html(response.html)
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$file = $_FILES['image'];


/* Allowed file extension */
$allowedExtensions = ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "svg"];

$fileExtension = explode(".", $file["name"]);

/* Contains file extension */
$extension = end($fileExtension);

/* Allowed Image types */
$types = ['image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg','image/svg+xml'];

if(in_array(strtolower($file['type']), $types) 
    // Checking for valid image type
    && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExtensions) 
    // Checking for valid file extension
    && !$file["error"] > 0)
    // Checking for errors if any
    { 
    if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], 'uploads/'.$file['name'])){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(['html' => /*return uploded file path and name*/ ]);    
        echo $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    }else{
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(['html' => 'Unable to move image. Is folder writable?']);    
    }
}else{    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['html' => 'Please upload only png, jpg images']);
}

?>
```

The code works, that is upload the file but I don't know how to get the path back. The path may change because its for a user profile image and later I will change the upload path to one that is /$username. If you know how get the name only please post that anyway. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$file['name']` has the name of the file in it, lets say `test1.png`

This is the bit of the program that saves your file in a specific location. In this case the folder `uploads` relative to the current working directory.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], 'uploads/'.$file['name'])){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['html' =>  
                       /* you might want to output something like */
                          getcwd().'/uploads/'.$file['name']
                        // getcwd()    current working directory
                        // it may be that you need a relative path based on 
                        // where your application lives to generate a url, for example
                        // 'http://your_app_base_url/'.'/uploads/'.$file['name']
                     ]);    
    echo $_FILES['upload']['name']; // this will be empty unless there is a file form field with the name 'upload' 
                                   // compare with $_FILE['image'] above
}else{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['html' => 'Unable to move image. Is folder writable?']);    
}
```

If you want to move the file later, you could have a directory called `profile_pics` and move them to there, and rename to the username.

e.g.

```
$oldfilename = $file['name'];

//create a name for the file based on username and uploaded file extension (.jpg/.png)
$newfilename = $username.'_profile.'.pathinfo($oldfilename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//this will rename /move the file from uploads to profile_pics (directory must exist already)
rename('uploads/'.$oldfilename,'profile_pics/'.$newfilename);
```

Comment: Thanks it work perfectly. I just removed the getcwd(). because that returned the full path with forward and back slashes C:\xampp\root\public/uploads/